# Unlocalize crispy forms field (such as latitude and longitude)

Tags: python, django, forms, localization, django-crispy-forms

I would like to have the values for latitude and longitude to always display a dot (".") instead of a comma (",") when showing the latitude and longitude form fields. 
This seems to be tricky with crispy forms.

In the template which shows the model's fields I just use

```
{% crispy form %}
```

But I did not find in the documentation of crispy forms how to do sth. like

```
{{ value|unlocalize }}
```

as provided by the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/formatting/#unlocalize). Since the crispy forms is supposed to be generic as in the following code example, I don't know where to set the trigger.

**extract from forms.py**

```
class CrispyForm(ModelForm):
"""
This form serves as a generic form for creating and updating items.
"""
helper = None

    def __init__(self, cancel_button, *args, **kwargs):
        form_action = kwargs.pop('form_action', None)
        model_name = kwargs.pop('model_name', None)
        super(CrispyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        if form_action is not None:
            action = reverse(form_action)
        else:
            action = ""

        # Form attributes
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = action
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-10'

        # Save button, having an offset to align with field_class
        save_text = _('Save %(model)s') % {'model': model_name}
        cancel_text = _('Cancel')
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save_form', save_text, css_class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2 save_item"))
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('cancel', cancel_text, css_class="btn btn-primary"))
```

**and here is a form which has model fields latitude and longitude**

```
class SomeItemCreateForm(CrispyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['form_action'] = 'create_someitem_url'
        kwargs['model_name'] = self._meta.model._meta.verbose_name
        super(SomeItemCreateForm, self).__init__(False, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

The SomeItem model has a longitude and latitude field amongst others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Layout Docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html)

You'll basically want to create a custom template for your field and then use that.

Your code will be a bit like this:

```
form = SomeItemCreateForm(...)
form.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('latitude', template='custom_field_template.html'),
    Field('longitude', template='custom_field_template.html')
)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: OK, this seems like a reasonable way to do it.